# how to echo a json statement from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

my issue is as following,i have to display an error msg in 3 cases
1- some text is missing
2- telephone number should be all digits
3- email format is invalid
the $errmsg is a JSON object that should display that message after being parsed in the ajax.but i don't know how to parse it in the ajax and return the value.
here is my code:

```
$errmsg='{"invalid":"some text missing",
      "mailerr":"email format is incorrect",
      "telephoneerr":"telephone should be all digits"}';
 if(($name=="")||($email=="")||($telephone=="")||($username=="")||($password==""))
{
  echo $errmsg;
}elseif(!preg_match($pattern_email,$email)){
 echo $errmsg;
}
elseif (!preg_match($pattern_phone,$telephone)){
  echo $errmsg;
 }
```

and the ajax code is as follows:

```
  $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'contactData.php',
          //dataType: "JSON",     
 data{"name":name,"telephone":telephone,"email":email,"username":username,"password":password},
       success: function(data) {            
      $("#validate").html(data);     
       }        
    });
```

Comment: Are you open to a method not using a JSON object? Looks to me each message can be sent in plain text, individually, simplifying things. I also suggest validating input both on the client before sending the Ajax AND on the server.

Comment: $errmsg is from MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$errmsg='{"invalid":"some text missing",
         "mailerr":"email format is incorrect",
         "telephoneerr":"telephone should be all digits"}';

if (($name == "") || ($email == "") || ($telephone == "") || ($username == "") || ($password == "") || !preg_match($pattern_email, $email) || !preg_match($pattern_phone, $telephone)){
    return $errmsg;
}
```

## UPDATE

If you want to parse the JSON data using jQuery, then can check the below code:

```
<?php
if (($name == "") || ($email == "") || ($telephone == "") || ($username == "") || ($password == "")) {
    $errorMsg = array("error" => "some text missing");
} elseif (!preg_match($pattern_email, $email)) {
    $errorMsg = array("error" => "email format is incorrect");
} elseif (!preg_match($pattern_phone, $telephone)){
    $errorMsg = array("error" => "telephone should be all digits");
}

return json_encode($errorMsg);
?>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'contactData.php',
        dataType: "JSON",     
        data{"name":name, "telephone":telephone, "email":email, "username":username, "password":password},
        success: function(data) {
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $("#validate").html(data.error);     
        }        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what am i supposed to write in the ajax function? i was asked to parse the json in the ajax but i didnt understand what does that mean

Comment: please check my updated code, hope it will help you.

Comment: sorry for asking so much but im new to json.but why should i declare the messages and i already declared them in the php code. second question if i parsed them in the ajax, how will the program now that this message is for this error if there is nothing in the ajax hat indicates that??

Answer (score 0):

You can use "dataType:JSON" in ajax(in jQuery) and instead of

```
$errmsg='{"invalid":"some text missing",
  "mailerr":"email format is incorrect",
  "telephoneerr":"telephone should be all digits"}';
```

return an array with json_encode like this in php

```
echo json_encode(array("invalid" => "some text missing",
  "mailerr" => "email format is incorrect",
  "telephoneerr" => "telephone should be all digits"));
```

Now you can access your array values as objects like

```
data.invalid OR data.mailerr
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSON is badly formed. Try writing it without the outer pair of single quotes, as follows:

```
$errmsg = {
    "invalid"      : "some text missing",
    "mailerr"      : "email format is incorrect",
    "telephoneerr" : "telephone should be all digits"
};
```

and then calling `$errmsg['invalid']`, etc to get the required error message for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your output is correct and u need to show that in jquery

```
  $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
         url: 'contactData.php',

         //dataType: "JSON",
    data{"name":name,"telephone":telephone,"email":email,"username":username,"password":password},
   success: function(data) {

  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

  $("#validate").html(obj.invalid);



   }        
});
```